# Java "Error occurred during initialization of VM" fix?

Tags: java, initialization, virtual-machine

I was trying to make a Minecraft server and got the following error on startup:

> Error occured during initialization of VM
>   Could not reserve enough space for object heap
>   Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine
>   Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.

I tried everything I could find: I created CLASS and CLASSPATH environmental variables that went to my Java's bin folder. I re-installed java, making sure it was 64 bit, as my computer is. Still, I get this error. Does anyone know a solution?

Comment: Add more memory to your heap using `-Xmx` argument.

Comment: I am shocked that when you googled that error there were no results ...

Comment: How much RAM does your machine have?

Answer (score 4):

You are attempting to allocate more RAM than your system will allow you to allocate.

In your startup script, lower the values of your Xmx/Xms arguments.

Comment: +1 Increasing the heap will help if you get an OutOfMemoryError after the JVM starts, this error means there isn't enough system memory to allocate the heap in the first place.

Comment: @PeterLawrey indeed, either not enough or the system won't allow you to overcommit that particular amount of memory (Linux's `overcommit_memory` comes to mind)

Comment: Or there is not enough continuous/virtual memory, something 32-bit Windows can have a problem with.  The heap has to be continuous in virtual memory.

Answer (score 1):

My issue was resolved after I reinstalled latest version of JDK.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32228737)

Answer (score 0):

Run the JVM with `-XX:MaxHeapSize=256m` (or any big number), and possibly `-Xmx512m`

Comment: I believe those two flags are equivalent

Comment: Yes you are right -Xms and -Xmx are only shortcuts which are internally mapped to -XX:InitialHeapSize and -XX:MaxHeapSize.

Answer (score 0):

I've actually noticed this issue when you try and take a dump of a service running java.
Try using psexec -s to execute your dump

I'm not sure why this seems to work on some servers and not others

Answer (score 0):

I had this same error. Running the cmd as Administrator resolved it.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this error when I was trying to build selenium webdriver. as suggested above by Rogue that we need to reduce the allocated memory in the arguments.

I changed java heap size arguments as below

```
java $JAVA_OPTS -Xmx256m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=256m -jar third_party/jruby/jruby-complete.jar -X-C -S rake $*
```

Answer (score 0):

I also faced this issue by My IntellijIDEA allocate more jvm memory space than system allocated.
My issued is resolved through  just uninstall the JDK and install it again.

Answer (score 0):

It happened to me also.  My eclipse would not run.  Uninstalled and reinstalled eclipse like 3 time and no luck.  Came to this question during a google search, and Yasir's answer helped me out, because I also had IntelliJ installed into my DEV BOX recently.  So deleted C:\Program Files\Java folder and reinstalled java into default install folder and it worked.  I also had jdk in my system path from previous setup.